# Is this a bug in Android GregorianCalendar?

Tags: android, debugging, gregorian-calendar

So, it's the 26th of January 2015, and I have the following code running on an android device;

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();

// Set date to 4 weeks ago, and then use it for the first BETWEEN date in the above query    
date.set(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, date.get(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)-4);
System.out.println(df.format(new Date(date.getTimeInMillis())));
// Set date to 2 weeks time, and then use it for the second BETWEEN date in the above query

date.set(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, date.get(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)+6);
System.out.println(df.format(new Date(date.getTimeInMillis())));
```

And I get the output;

```
29/12/14 10:29
09/02/14 10:29
```

Running this snippet on standard Java on a Windows machine shows the correct results with the second date as `09/02/15 10:29`. So on Android, it is correctly rolling the year back when we ask for the date to go back 4 weeks, but when we ask it to go forward 6 weeks (past our original date), it is not rolling the year forward again.

I have observed this on 5.0.2 and 4.4.2

**So the question is, is this a bug or some kind of convoluted intended behavior(*feature*)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a complexity of how certain `Calendar` fields are computed and handled and it's *not* a bug. The fact you're using arithmetic adjustments rather than using the `add(...)` method is probably also complicating things.

From the docs...

> The first week of a month or year is defined as the earliest seven day period beginning on getFirstDayOfWeek() and containing at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days of that month or year.

In this case the first week of the year, i.e., `WEEK_OF_YEAR = 1`, starts on the 4th or 5th of January depending on if the first day of the week is set to Sunday or Monday respectively.

The `Calendar` class is abstract and different implementations of concrete classes which extend it may behave differently but it is allowable to have a 0 or even -1 index for weeks in a year. The fact that the dates 1st -> 3rd or 1st -> 4th (depending on first day of week) obviously fall within the year 2015 means the week starting 28th or 29th of December is classed as week 0.

The 26th of January falls within the `WEEK_OF_YEAR = 4` (regardless of first day of week) and consequently when you subtract 4 from the current `WEEK_OF_YEAR` it returns 0 and adjusts the date to the Monday in that week, i.e., 29th December.

The problem comes when you add 6 weeks to the previously adjusted date - at this point it is 29th December 2014. As I said, you are using arithmetic adjustment rather than using the `add(...)` method. As you're not adjusting the year manually, it assumes it should remain within 2014 and by adding 6 weeks you're causing an overflow / rollback to the beginning of 2014 instead of it dynamically adjusting the `YEAR` as well as the `WEEK_OF_YEAR` etc.

Comment: Accepted because this explains the odd results I was seeing, and answers the direct question. Thanks.

Comment: @Rudi : Glad I could shed some light. The key thinks are that any field which is named using `_OF_` (examples `HOUR_OF_DAY`, `WEEK_OF_YEAR`, `DAY_OF_MONTH` etc) will generally overflow and rollback to the beginning of whatever they represent. It's tricky and, as I said, not a bug - more an oddity.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `Calendar.set` for this. You're trying to set the week field to an invalid value and hope that it can figure out your intended meaning. This may work for the desktop JVM, but you shouldn't rely on it and - apparently - Android's implementation indeed handles it differently.

Use `Calendar.add` instead, which actually does what you want: add or subtract from a field with the proper adjustments.

```
date.add(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -4);
date.add(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 6);
```

Comment: Thank you. This was not the answer I was looking for, but it was the answer I needed.